# Python : How to append new section to existing XML

Tags: python

I have a simple XML file and need to add `<item>`
Tried it with ElementTree but got lost...

So - from this :

```
<channel>
<title>Latest Critical Tickets</title>
<channelName>Critical </channelName>
<item>
    <title>Ticket number 01</title>
        <link>https://blablabla.com/01</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2021 16:45:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
```

To this :

```
<channel>
<title>Latest Critical Tickets</title>
<channelName>Critical </channelName>
<item>
    <title>Ticket number 01</title>
        <link>https://blablabla.com/01</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2021 16:45:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
<item>
    <title>Ticket number 02</title>
        <link>https://blabl12abla.com/01</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 16 Jul 2021 21:13:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>
```

thanks in advnaced!

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do what you need:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.dom import minidom

root = ET.fromstring("""<channel>
<title>Latest Critical Tickets</title>
<channelName>Critical </channelName>
<item>
    <title>Ticket number 01</title>
        <link>https://blablabla.com/01</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 14 Jul 2021 16:45:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>
</channel>""")

element_to_add = ET.fromstring("""<item>
    <title>Ticket number 02</title>
        <link>https://blabl12abla.com/01</link>
        <pubDate>Wed, 16 Jul 2021 21:13:00 GMT</pubDate>
</item>""")

root.insert(-1, element_to_add)

print(minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   "))
```

Comment: Thanks ! I used a print to XML file with yours to append only the <item> section to the existing XML but it keeps writing the whole XML any time executed. Can you suggest how to add only the <item> ? without <channel> and <title>

Comment: Any idea @osint_alex ?